# Error creating new repo using GitHub desktop

Tags: javascript, git, github-for-mac

When trying to create a new repo I am receiving the following error message. Notice that the folder `javascripting` has a / at the end of it.

This is not on the file name but it shows up by itself. Also, the 5 boxes that are normally green are grayed out.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to verify that the `javascripting` does not have `.git` folder inside it.

Once you remove this folder you will be able to `clone / pull`.

If there is a `.git` folder inside it might be sub modulate and someone commited it by mistake or did not define the submodule properly.

Comment: @CodeWizaard I checked and no .git folder inside. Just some .js a README.md & LICENSE.md files.

Comment: Is it a public repository? so i can look on it? and have you verified that you can see hidden folders (.git is a hidden folder) you have to list it with `ls -la`

Comment: Actually I do see a .git folder when viewing with ```ls -la```. Here is the folder link https://github.com/BlackGuyCoding/NodeSchool

Comment: As mentioned in the answer :-). You know what to do to fix it as described in the answer. remove it and you are good to work. In the github repo i dont see it so you must have it locally.  You also have file with spaces. Try to avoid it

Comment: This file: https://github.com/BlackGuyCoding/NodeSchool/blob/master/javascripting/1:%20introduction.js

Comment: delete the .git folder and continue with your work. Glad to help.